# ValueError: output name: logits/BiasAdd, was provided, but the Tensorflow graph does not contain a tensor with this name

Tags: python, tensorflow, model, coreml

I working on a project that detects eye region and I have a frozen inference model.
I'm trying to convert this model to .mlmodel ( using tfcoreml ) but I have got this error :

> ValueError: output name: logits/BiasAdd was provided, but the Tensorflow graph does not contain a tensor with this name.

But the tensor is existed on the graph, this :
[image: graph of the model]

**+ This is the input tensor(input_to_float) :**

[image: Input tensor]

**+ This is the output tensor(logits/BiasAdd):**

[image: output tensor]

and this the code that I use for converting:

```py
import tfcoreml as tf_converter
tf_converter.convert(tf_model_path='C:\\Users\\User\\cnn-facial-landmark\\irismodel\\freeze2\\frozen_inf_model_iris.pb',
                     mlmodel_path='irismodelios.mlmodel',
                     output_feature_names=['logits/BiasAdd'],
                     input_name_shape_dict={'input_to_float': [1, 112, 112, 3]})
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Try `logits/BiasAdd:0` with the `:0` at the end.

Comment: When I try `logits/BiasAdd:0` , I get other error >NotImplementedError: Unsupported Ops of type: OneShotterator,IteratorGetNext,Shape,Pack

Answer (score 0):

I can say that I solved my problem by following this: [How to use a retrained "tensorflow for poets" graph on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48117854/how-to-use-a-retrained-tensorflow-for-poets-graph-on-ios)

After optimizing the frozen graph, I get placeholder instead of OneShotterator, IteratorGetNext and cast.
Before converting: ( optimized graph )

, but I'm not sure because of I doubt that the input_to_float should have [1,112,112,3] instead of [3,112,112]:

Logs of CMD:

```
Core ML input(s):
[name: "input_to_float__0"
type {
multiArrayType {
shape: 3
shape: 112
shape: 112
dataType: DOUBLE
}
}
]
Core ML output(s):
[name: "logits__BiasAdd__0"
type {
multiArrayType {
shape: 80
dataType: DOUBLE
}
}
]
```

[image]

After converting ( .mlmodel file )

[image]